# Play 2.1-RC2: Converting JsValue to Scala Value

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am a play beginner and try to migrate my web application from Play 2.0.4 to the new shiny Play 2.1-RC2. My code doesn't compile because of the new JSON handling.

I have read [Mandubians Blog](http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/), the [Play 2.1 Migration guide](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Migration) and the [Play JSON library documentation (beta)](http://play2-docs-snapshot.herokuapp.com/render/master/ScalaJson) but I am still unsure what's the best way to migrate my code.

F.ex. I have a model called `File` with an implicit Read-Object (Play 2.0):

```
object File {
    implicit object FileReads extends Reads[File] {
      def reads(json: JsValue) = File(
        (json \ "name").as[String],
        (json \ "size").as[Long]
     )
   }
}
```

I use it like this in the controller (Play 2.0):

```
val file = webserviceResult.json.as[models.File]
```

The Play 2.1 Migration guide tells me to refactor it with a `JsSuccess()` like this (Play 2.1?):

```
object File {
    implicit object FileFormat extends Format[File] {
      def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(File(
        (json \ "name").as[String],
        (json \ "size").as[Long]
     ))
   }
}
```

But how can I use this implicit conversion now?

Or is it better to use the `implicit val`-stuff like in the [Twitter-example](https://github.com/playforscala/sample-applications/blob/master/ch10-webservices-iteratees-and-websockets/twitter/app/models/Tweet.scala) from the [Play for Scala-book](http://www.manning.com/hilton/)? Whats the best way to convert a JsValue to it's Scala value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Or is it better to use the implicit val-stuff like in the Twitter-example from the Play for Scala-book?

Yes, for a classic conversion, it's a good solution (simple and concise).

But there is a simpler way to achieve this conversion with the "[Json Macro Inception](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception)" :

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class File(name: String, size: Long)
implicit val fileFormat = Json.format[File]

val json = Json.parse("""{"name":"myfile.avi", "size":12345}""") // Your WS result

scala> json.as[File]
res2: File = File(myfile.avi,12345)
```

Warning: You cannot put your formater in the companion object, it's a limitation of the current Json API.

I advice to use an object with all you json formatters, and to import it when necessary.

FYI, the raw formater should be written like this:

```scala
implicit val rawFileRead: Format[File] = ( 
    (__ \ "name").format[String] and 
    (__ \ "size").format[Long]
)(File.apply _, unlift(File.unapply _)) // or (File, unlift(File.unapply))
```

Check these two test class, there are many interesting exemples:

- [JsonSpec](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsonSpec.scala)
- [JsonExtensionSpec](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsonExtensionSpec.scala)

Comment: Thanks, that really helps me a lot. After an `import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._` a lot of the compiler errors gone away. But I still have problems with case classes that only have _one_ argument: Something like `implicit val rawFileRead: Format[File] = ( (__ \ "name").format[String])(File.apply _, unlift(File.unapply _))` doesn't compile `Overloaded method value [read] cannot be applied to (String => File)`. But maybe this should be another SO-question...

Comment: The macro don't work with a single field caseclass (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/play-framework/hGrveOkbJ6U) I'm not sure, but check the code in the ticket